Has lithium hydride ever been tested as a rocket fuel?
I know about the Rocketdyne tripropellant rocket that burned $\ce{H2}$, $\ce{Li}$, and $\ce{F2}$ together, but why not use lithium hydride instead? Has anyone tried this, and if so, what was the performance?
Setting aside issues of cost and toxic exhaust products, what are the difficulties of working with $\ce{LiH}$? Is it corrosive?

Looks like it has been tested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_hydride#Hydrogen_storage_and_fuel

But having solid, and dangerous, combustion product (Li2O) isn't good.

Then again, the tripropellant Li+H2+F2 also gives a nonvolatile solid product, lithium fluoride. This is less dangerous than the oxide, but fluorine is more dangerous than oxygen.

Starting with LiH means you have less chemical energy to liberate since you have turned H2 and Li into a more stable compound.

This question is more suitable in Space Exploration.SE

See: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/52166/37747
